# Java Eratostenes sieve,printing only the biggest prime from a given ceiling?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sieve

everyone!I have a java app that shows all the prime numbers from 2 to a given number(user input).How can I print out just the last number, the biggest one I mean, from the given range?
For example:if the user input is 12,the compiler prints only 11,not 2,3,5,7,11.
Here is the code:

```
  package sieve_eratos;

   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Sieve_Eratos {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // get the ceiling on our prime numbers
    int N;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("enter the prime number ceiling: ");
    N = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();
    int k = 0;
    // init numbers array, where true denotes primality
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[N];
    // init possible primes
    isPrime[0] = false; // 1 is not prime
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        isPrime[i] = true;
        k = k + 1;

    }


    // check every number >= 2 for primality
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {

        // i is prime if it hasn't been "crossed off" yet
        if (isPrime[i - 1]) {

            // print out the prime number
            System.out.println(i);



            // "cross off" all the subsequent multiples of i
            //for (int j = 2*i; j <= N; j += i) {
            for (int j = i * i; j <= N; j += i) { // more efficient
                isPrime[j - 1] = false;

            }

        }

    }
}
}
```

I was thinking about creating another integer array and then calling the last element(which will be the last number stored),but I have no idea how to do this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to use a list instead of an array.

Comment: Why not do the program above and after the for loop just check your array in another for/while loop from back to front. Print number and stop after the first prime you have found.

Comment: @MarkusKoivisto the key to [the sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)'s efficiency is in using array, not list, to have random access. To count and just mark the multiples, not actually removing the numbers, to preserve the ability to directly address (and mark) other multiples.

Comment: Yeah it's better to just store the index of the last found prime in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NavigableSet.lower](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#lower%28E%29). Take a look at following example

```
Integer primeValues[]={2,3,5,7,11};//Here store all primes 
NavigableSet<Integer> primeCollec=new TreeSet<>();
primeCollec.addAll(Arrays.asList(primeValues));
                      //Add all range prime into NavigableSet

int input=12;// Get the user input here
int output=primeCollec.lower(input);// Here is the desired output based on input

System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbers are **consecutive numbers** (from 1 to N), we can check the Prime number flags (in your code, it is  **boolean[] isPrime** )from biggest index.

If it is true, then the sum of its index and 1 (index+1) will be the ceiling prime we want.

Code is as follows:

```
public static int populateCeilingPrime(boolean[] flags)
{
int len = flags.length;
for(int i= len -1;i>=0;i--)
{
    if(flags[i])
    {
        return i+1;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

so you just need to call this method above to populate the ceiling prime, using the following code at the end of main method.

```
System.out.printf("The ceiling prime is %d ", populateCeilingPrime(isPrime));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the prime, you could make a check if the number you want to print is larger than some earlier number you wanted to print and then if it is prime, and larger, you save that prime as the biggest so far. Once you are done with your sieveing process, that saved prime should be what you want.

Like so:

```
int maxPrime = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {

    // i is prime if it hasn't been "crossed off" yet
    if (isPrime[i - 1]) {
        if(i > maxPrime) {
             maxPrime = i;
        }

        // "cross off" all the subsequent multiples of i
        //for (int j = 2*i; j <= N; j += i) {
        for (int j = i * i; j <= N; j += i) { // more efficient
            isPrime[j - 1] = false;

        }

    }

}
System.out.println(maxPrime);
```

Comment: that's much too much work. why not search the sieved array back from the top, after it is fully sieved. That's O(log N) step instead of O(N/log N).

Comment: I dont see how it is much to much work. Instead of doing another search he will have the maximum as soon as the sieving is done. But im not gonna argue, i have not analyzed my approach from a complexity point of view.

Comment: you are doing O(N/log N) operations (updating `maxPrime` variable for each found prime) to spare O(log N) operations (i.e. counting down from the top of the array to the first non-marked entry). complexity-wise, the *average* space between neighboring primes is O(log N).

Comment: my pleasure. :) I should have been clearer in my first comment. It should've been *"why not search the sieved array back from the top, after it is fully sieved. That's O(log N) steps instead of O(N/log N)* steps".